# ManyToManyField of Django model populated unexpectedly

Tags: python, django, backend

I'm currently working on a site with Django on Python 3. The site allows users to follow projects that they like, and they can follow as many as you want, as long as the thot projects exist. Here are my models of the site.

This is my Team model, which is the model for all the projects you can follow

```
class Team(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='team')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/team_images', blank=True)
    roster = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    current_raise = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    # current_backers = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    time_left = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=timezone.now)
    raising_minimum = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
    raising_maximum = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
    duration = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is the user profile mode, I have a Many-to-Many field in this model.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField('accounts.User')
     following = models.ManyToManyField(Team,                 related_name='user_following', blank=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.user.first_name

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if self.pk:
             for team in self.following:
                 team.save()
         super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The problem is, when I check the database, all the teams I've created for testing are in the field `following` **even though** the user hasn't requested to follow them, yet.

All the teams I have created showed up under 'following' in admin page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Gap.png)

Comment: Do you mean that all the teams appear in the dropdown menu in the admin to choose from?

Comment: what you mean "they are in the following field"? m2m should create separate table between UserProfile and Team.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Hi, I edited my post, I added a screenshot of my admin page, under following, there are three teams I have created, they are not suppose to be there yet because the user hasn't followed them.

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov Hi, the teams I created before showed up in the following field. They are not suppose to be there because the user hasn't followed them yet.

Comment: @RobertLi they just show possible values the user can choose from! if you click on any of them then it will be highlighted = chosen. It should be like that.

Comment: In your screenshot, the users aren't selected : the selector is a bit crappy, but only those that are highlighted are the 'selected ones'. This should be reflected on the DB side too...

Comment: Yes same thing as @AlexanderTyapkov

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov Is this the best way to create this following/follower mechanism?

Comment: @sknat Hi, the user isn't selected because I was creating a new UserProfile object, it hasn't relate to any user yet

Comment: @RobertLi no, I can suggest you to use separate model Follow in which you will have the key to the User or User profile and another key for Team. But it goes out of your question scope.

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov Why would I need another key for Team in the separate model 'Follow'? and also why would I need a separate model 'Follow'? In the model 'UserProfile' shown above, I already have a key for user, and keys for all the teams. Sorry, I'm new to django :(

Comment: @RobertLi you have asked if it is the best way or not. You can also do as you did and it will work, but in my case I have a lot of other fields in UserProfile and I don't want to mess all the things up. More then that I have Followers as a separate app which I can reuse in the future. That is why separate model is better option, but it is IMHO. You have asked - i have answered)

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options displayed in the m2m multiple choice field of admin site are just options you can choose from. It is expected behavior of Django admin. To choose some options you can just click on the item or if you want to choose multiple click with CTRL pressed.

Comment: what's the best way to contact you? I'm new to the site.

Comment: @RobertLi check if there is my email in the profile or chat. Otherwise just send an email on "my surname" at gmail.